# Исправление отправленного/полученного POST запроса/ответа к 1с на PHP

Tags: php

прошу объяснить тайны бытия на PHP

```
$server='http://188.17.157.70:82/test3/hs/';//test

//PHP
$ch       = curl_init();//инициализируем
$data     = json_encode($array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);//данные
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_1c);//адрес
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);//?
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);//?
$result  = curl_exec($ch);//посылаем, и получаем ответ
curl_close($ch);//закрываем соединение

//смотрим что в ответе
echo '<pre>['; print_r($result); echo ']</pre>';
```

Получаю вот такой ответ

```
//вариант 1, ошибка ( все пошло не так )
Ошибка инициализации модуля: НазваниеМодуль..[]
```

квадратные скобки, те, что содержат ответ - пусты, и ДО них вывод ошибки

```
//вариант 2, все норм, как бы ( возвращается 2 ответа, т.е. 2 json )
{"status":"ok","data":["key1":"val1","key2":"val2"]}[]{"status":"true"}
```

получаю как будь то бы 2 ответа

Подскажите, как переписать PHP код так, что бы в случае ошибки, или ЛЮБОМ другом ответе, я получал все в переменную PHP.

p.s.
Вопрос не как исправить 1с, а как работать с тем что есть, т.к. обработка ошибок на PHP тоже вещь полезная

Comment: а вы, разве не получаете в переменную `$result` ? Другой вопрос не как получить в переменную, а как сделать выборку из `json` в случае ошибки.

Comment: $result - пуст. в том то и дело. Кроме того, вывод идет по мимо $result, что ломает все планы ) Вот хочу что бы мне посоветовали чудо коменду какую ни будь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

оказалось решить вопрос можно так!

Есть параметр CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , который и позволяет отдавать ответ в переменную

```
//PHP
$ch       = curl_init();//инициализируем
$data     = json_encode($array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);//данные

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);//вот оно, решение
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Что мешает просто использовать `file_get_contents`? Или у вас он не поддерживается?

Answer (score 1):

```
function isJson($string) {
    return ((is_string($string) &&
        (is_object(json_decode($string)) ||
        is_array(json_decode($string))))) ? true : false;
}

if (isJson($result)) {
// Все ОК
} else {
// Ошибка
}
```

Comment: вопрос не в том, как проверить JSON или нет, а как получить ответ в переменную, т.к. ответ не всегда JSON

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '{"status":"ok","data":["key1":"val1","key2":"val2"]}[]{"status":"true"}';

function json_validate($string)
{
    // decode the JSON data
    $result = json_decode($string);

    // switch and check possible JSON errors
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            $error = ''; // JSON is valid // No error has occurred
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            $error = 'The maximum stack depth has been exceeded.';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            $error = 'Invalid or malformed JSON.';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            $error = 'Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded.';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            $error = 'Syntax error, malformed JSON.';
            break;
        // PHP >= 5.3.3
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            $error = 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.';
            break;
        // PHP >= 5.5.0
        case JSON_ERROR_RECURSION:
            $error = 'One or more recursive references in the value to be encoded.';
            break;
        // PHP >= 5.5.0
        case JSON_ERROR_INF_OR_NAN:
            $error = 'One or more NAN or INF values in the value to be encoded.';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE:
            $error = 'A value of a type that cannot be encoded was given.';
            break;
        default:
            $error = 'Unknown JSON error occured.';
            break;
    }

    if ($error !== '') {
        throw new \Exception($error);  // or whatever :)
    }

    // everything is OK
    return true;
}

try {
    json_validate($str);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: Как же хорошо, что в php 7.3 добавят собственные исключения для json_encode

Comment: вопрос не в валидности JSON, а в том, как ответ POST в переменную получить